# What to change from ereg_replace to preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, ereg-replace

I've just upgraded to php 5.4 and I've come across a common error of needing to upgrade my ereg_replace to preg_replace, but I'm a tad confused.

How can I change the following ereg_replace to a preg_replace?

```
ereg_replace("&page=[0-9]+","",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

`preg_replace("/&page=[0-9]+/","",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);`

Hope this helps :)